# Scrapy: After using `start_requests()` to make urls,`start_urls` is also necessary?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am using Scrapy 1.1,
my question is:

After using `start_requests()` to make urls,`start_urls` is also necessary?
Can I delete it?

For example：

```
class demoSpider(RedisSpider):
    name = "demospider"

    #Can I delete `start_urls`?
    redis_key = 'demospider:start_urls'
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        pages=[]
        for i in range(1,10):
            url='http://www.example.com/?page=%s'%i
            page=scrapy.Request(url)
            pages.append(page)
        return pages
```

Comment: Nope, it won't make any difference, you can remove it. You could of course just create a list comp and forget using start_requests

Answer (score 2):

All scrapy spiders must inherit from `scrapy.Spider` (or it's children like `scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider`)
If you open this class up you'll see that `self.start_urls` is only used in `start_requests` method.

So if you override the inherited `start_requests` method, `start_urls` is no longer used anywhere and can be undefined or deleted.